# picture not getting posted on facebook page from localhost

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the following code to publish to my page's wall through my Facebook app

```
$params = array(
    // this is the main access token (facebook profile)
   "access_token" => $access_token,
   "message" => "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook without being signed in using PHP #php #facebook",
   "link" => $AD_Link,
   "picture" => "https://localhost/adwit1/uploaded_images/himanshu124/Lighthouse.jpg",
   "name" => $AD_Name,
   "caption" => $AD_Caption,
   "description" => $AD_Desc
);

try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook Personal Profile '.$ret['id'];
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Using this code everything is getting posted on my FB page except the image specified. However if I directly paste the image link mentioned above in the browser i am able to view the image. On the other hand if i use the following link https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzKcZ.png in the "picture" parameter the image gets posted on the FB page.

I also found a similar problem here on stackoverflow.com, however there was no satisfactory answer mentioned.

Please help me if someone is aware as to why i am facing such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You facing this problem because facebook can't read localhost server, The only one who can read your localhost is you, No one else.

You are able to view the following image because it's on your localhost.

```
https://localhost/adwit1/uploaded_images/himanshu124/Lighthouse.jpg
```

To solve this problem, Upload the images on any image store website then get its link, In this case, Facebook will be able to read the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/facebook.php";

class FacebookLib{

    private $CI;

    /**
     * loading codeIgniter instance
     */
    public function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function postOnFaceBook(){
        $config = array();
        $config['appId'] = '*********';
        $config['secret'] = '********';
        $config['fileUpload'] = true; // optional
        $fb = new Facebook($config);

        //$user = $fb->getUser();
        //echo $access_token = $fb->getAccessToken();
        /*print_r($user);
        if($user){
            echo $fb->getAccessToken();
        }
        exit;*/
        //$access_token = 
        $param = array();
        $param['access_token'] = "********";
        //$param['access_token'] = $access_token;
        $param['message'] = "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP #php #facebook6";
        $param['link'] = "http://localhost/FreightBazaar/";
        $param['picture'] = "http://yoururl.com/assets/images/customer/profile/1476700963.3612driver-app-ico--4-.png";
        $param['name'] ="How to Auto Post on Facebook with PHP";
        $param['caption'] ="";
        $param['description'] ="Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation.";


        // post to Facebook
        // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
        try {
            $ret = $fb->api('/page id/feed', 'POST', $param);
            return "Successfully posted to Facebook";
            //$ret = $fb->api('/page id/feed', 'POST', $params);
            //echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            return $e;
            //echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Locahost url not identified so use live site url link ......e.g `www.example.com/images/profile.png`